# I have one Login and index page. I want to redirect from index to login but get 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have just started developing spring boot with thymleaf. I have an index and a login page and I want to redirect from index to login but getting 404 error. I have studied stackoverflow problem but still getting error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0YPr.png)
Index Contorller:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @PostMapping(path = "loginPage")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

Index page hyperlink:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

...
...
...
<a th:href="@{loginPage}" class="banner-button btn mt-md-5 mt-3 ml-3 mr-3 scroll">Login</a>

...
...
...
```

Expected result will be login page in the browser but actual output is coming spring-boot whitelable error page with status 400

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jun 23 15:23:49 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Put `Controller` instead `RestController`

Comment: Try adding a `/` here `path = "/loginPage"` and/or here `return "/login";`.

Comment: nothing happened above two solution @WizardCoder Ebrahim Pasbani

Comment: If you are using spring-security, then login has a very special behavior. Also, what is the full path of your index page template source file?

Comment: index: /SpringBootStu/src/main/resources/templates/index.html
login: /SpringBootStu/src/main/resources/templates/login.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Controller` instead of `RestController` and also the `<a>` tag initiates a `GET`.

So the code should be like:

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/loginPage")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

And also in view:

```
<a th:href="@{/loginPage}" class="banner-button ...
```

or

```
<a th:href="loginPage" class="banner-button ...
```

Comment: Nothing happened sir I have just copy and pasted your code

Comment: beware `login` vs `loginPage`. I can find no indication as to the actual name of the template.

Comment: @tucuxi Yes. `loginPage` is the path of the method and `login` is the template name. The answer should be right

Comment: Some extra lines are showing in console:
```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\prama\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/prama/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/prama/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/prama/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,

```

Comment: Sir, Even debugger is not coming to the  method part

Comment: @ankurpramanik Please use in view like: `<a th:href="/loginPage" class="banner-button ...`

Comment: I have to use``` <a th:href="/loginPage" class="banner-button ...``` other wise got exception

Comment: can you give me a git hub repository address where i can get a full project of this topic

Comment: @ankurpramanik No I don't. By the way I think this answer is right. Because you had problem with `PostMapping` and `RestController`.

Comment: Yes. I got the problem and resolved it. putting ```@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.springbootthymleaf.controller" })``` on main class